# Is there a way to create OpenGL Texture from a cl_image?

Tags: opengl, opencl

To create a `cl_image` from an `OpenGL` texture we can use the following method:

`gcl_gl_create_image_from_texture`

What's the best way to create an `OpenGL` texture from a `cl_image` ?

Comment: You can't create an `OpenGL` texture from an `OpenCL` image.

Comment: Of course you can, the most naive approach would involve `gcl_map_image (...)` and passing the data to `glTexImage2D (...)` but that clearly involves a client memory copy.

Comment: OK, you can't create an *interop* `OpenGL` texture from an `OpenCL` image.